# If I want to execute a method every x seconds y times, should I use NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nstimer

I want to make something different appear every 2 seconds say, 10 times. How would I go about achieving this in Objective-C?

I was thinking about using NSTimer and invalidating it after so many seconds, like in the above example 2 * 10 seconds after I start the timer. Or is there a way to measure the ticks?

Or I was considering a for loop and using the performSelector:withDelay: method.

Which would be preferable?

Comment: Use the repeating timer. Also have a class property that is an integer to keep track of how many times your timer has been called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) and set the time `interval` as `2 seconds` and `repeats` to `YES`.

Count the number of times that it triggered. `Invalidate`  when it reaches 10.Thats it

**Code:**

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(trigger:) userInfo:yourObject repeats:YES];

- (void)trigger:(NSTimer *)sender{

    id yourObject = sender.userInfo;

    static int count = 1;

    @try {

        NSLog(@"triggred %d time",count);

        if (count == 10){

            [sender invalidate];
            NSLog(@"invalidated");
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
    }
    @finally {

        count ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I count the number of times it was triggered within the method I call? And how do I invalidate it when it reaches that limit?

Comment: I have added the methods... please check it'

Comment: What if I wanted 10 to change to a different number perhaps based on the usage. Can I have parameters for the method?

Comment: Yes, pass it through NSTimer UserInfo. I have edited the answer now.. plz check it

Answer (score 3):

i used the second option of you, no timer needed

```
for (int a=0; a<10; a++) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(print) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0*a];
}


-(void)print
{
    NSLog(@"sth");
}
```

you may make the interval and repeat count flexible.